# What is the cleanest way to test if a Python Task or Future has completed successfully?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

What is the cleanest way to test that a python `Task` or `Future` has completed successfully (neither canceled nor failed)? This is the best I have come up with:

```
success = future.done() and not future.cancelled() and future.exception() is None
```

and it seems clumsy and error-prone, because it is easy to forget the `not future.cancelled()`.

Comment: And when `success` is `False` how do you know whether it's because the future hasn't completed or it has completed but it just wasn't successful. If it hasn't completed, then re-testing later might give a different result.

Comment: That is out of scope for the question, but you can use future.done() to differentiate between completed successfully and not yet done.

Comment: *"but you can use future.done() to differentiate between completed successfully and not yet done."* I realize that and that is exactly the point that I was trying to make, whether it was in scope or not. Perhaps I should have been clearer in my comment, but ultimately I was *trying* to imply that because of the need for a future test when `success` is False, that it is not a very useful test.

Answer (score 1):

It is looking good for me.
You can wrap in a function if you prefer:

```
def is_success(future):
   return future.done() and not future.cancelled() and future.exception() is None
```